# Default file descriptor table not working properly

Tags: c, file, unix, stdout, file-descriptor

I am having some trouble with file descriptors. The standard fd table on a POSIX-compliant system should, for each process, have stdin as 0, stdout as 1, and stderr as 2. Thereafter, file descriptors should be issued sequentially, so a request to open() a new file should return the file descriptor 3.

This does not happen on my system. Code which was working a few hours ago has ceased to do so. Because it is very long and messy code, I have written a quick example of the sort of thing I am seeing.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    int fToWrite;
    char *outFileName = "chuckles.txt";

    if (fToWrite = open(outFileName,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr,"error during open!: %s\n",strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    write(fToWrite,"kekeke",6);
    fprintf(stderr,"fToWrite = %i\n",fToWrite);
    close(fToWrite);
}
```

On my machine, after running this code, chuckles.txt is created, but nothing is written to it. To the console is printed:

```
kekekefToWrite = 0
```

Note that kekeke was not written to chuckles.txt, and that fToWrite, the file descriptor of the file I open()ed, is 0. But 0 is reserved for stdin. Likewise, if I try to fprintf to STDOUT_FILENO (which is the int 1) or STDERR_FILENO (which is 2), I get a segfault. In the main program I am trying to write, the program segfaults when I try to write() to STDOUT_FILENO. A few hours ago, the same code snippets would happily put letters on the console; I don't know what changed. I've rebooted, but I don't know what else to do about it.

Strangely, printf still works. I was under the impression that printf just wrote to whatever was in the fd table's #2 entry.

Comment: More generally, the file descriptor table is so central to Unix, that you should believe it is working correctly (otherwise your kernel is completely useless). Don't believe "the file descriptor table is not working" (becaue it is always working) but "what did I do wrong" at first!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra pair of parentheses:

```
if ((fToWrite = open(outFileName,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC)) < 0) {
```

That's why **fToWrite** gets the value 0.

Answer (score 0):

`<` has higher precedence than `=`, so you are assigning the result of `open(outFileName,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC) < 0` to `fToWrite`, which is either `0` or `1`.

So you end up writing to your terminal.